# What is the difference between "not a lot" and "not very much / not much"

Tags: word-usage

When I'm speaking English, I think I use *not a lot* and *not much* interchangeably. I've thought that maybe grammatically there is a difference between the phrases.

Are there cases where I should use *not a lot* instead of *not much*, or can I use them interchangeably?

> I don't like Japanese food very much.

> I don't like Japanese food a lot.

> I don't watch TV very much.

> I don't watch TV a lot.

> I don't know much about Western history.

> I don't know a lot about Western history.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What great examples!

As for the last set of sentences: I'd call them just about interchangeable, except that "a lot" would be regarded as less formal. (NOAD tags "a lot" as "informal," e.g.) If I was proofreading my own writing, I'd probably change "I don't know a lot about" to "I don't know much about." Either would be fine in conversation, though.

> **I don't know much about Western history**. {okay}
>   **I don't know a lot about Western history**. {okay in conversation, perhaps a bit informal for writing}

As for the middle set: I'd rephrase the latter sentence to read, "I don't watch a lot of TV." The first one could also be rephrased ("I don't watch very much TV"), but those two sentences have slightly different meanings: "I don't watch TV very much" would probably be interpreted as "I don't watch TV very **often**"; while "I don't watch very much TV" sounds more like "I don't watch many TV **programs**". The difference is very subtle, but I think it's existent. If I watched a half hour of TV nightly, but always the same program, I'd be inclined to say, "I don't watch a lot of TV," but not, "I don't watch TV very much." (After all, I watch nightly!)

> **I don't watch TV very much**. {you don't watch TV very often}
>   **I don't watch a lot of TV**. {you don't watch too many TV programs}
>   **I don't watch TV a lot**. {not wrong per se, but I'd recommed one of the others}

As for the first set, that latter sentence sounds off to me. Interestingly enough, I have no problem with its inverse: "I like Japanese food a lot." However, when speaking in the negative, "I don't like Japanese food very much" sounds much more polished than "I don't like .. a lot."

> **I don't like Japanese food very much**.
>   **I don't like Japanese food a lot**. {use the first one, not this one}
>
> **I like Japanese food very much**.
>   **I like Japanese food a lot**. {in the positive, you can use either one}

I'm marveling how, even though the three pairs of examples all have the same sentence structure, my comments are different for all three. I guess this is a trickier problem than one might first expect.

Comment: +1 I think your first substantive paragraph nails it: **1. in formal registers**, *much*, whether positive or negative, is preferred; **2. in less formal registers**, positive *lot* is preferred and negative *much* and *lot* are about on a par. Where and how the terms fall in the sentence is a matter of focus.

Comment: @J.R. Here I wanted to know the differences dependeing on the context, if any, even though they are subtle.  Your answer solved all my questions. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Sorry, let me ask one more question here.  How about a positive sentence in the first example.   "I know much about" , and "I know a lot about".  Do they both work?

Comment: @tennisgirl: "I know a lot about..." sounds more natural to me. It's not that "much" couldn't work, but "a lot" flows better. Hard to say why.

Comment: @J.R.  Thnak you very much.  It's clear.

Answer (score 2):

There's not a lot of difference. I mean, there's not very much difference. :-)

I think all of your examples are pretty much equivalent.

I agree with JR that "a lot" is less formal.

I'd quibble with JR on the distinctions he makes in the TV and Japanese food examples. I think in both cases, "a lot" and "very much" are acceptable in informal context and mean the same thing.

Comment: I'll grant you that the nuances I've described are very subtle and not glaring. If I was proofreading a scripted speech, I'd strive to use the more "accurate" wording, based on what the speaker would be trying to convey. In everyday conversation, there is a negligible difference.

Comment: @Jay.  Thank you very much for your answer.  It's very helpful, also.